# mysql - use count for specific value

Tags: mysql

I am using the below mysql command.

```
select count(sig_priority), convert((min(timestamp) div 500)*500 , datetime) as time
from events_with_join 
where (timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-10 14:05:00' AND '2018-06-10 15:05:00' )
group by timestamp div 500
```

1. How can I use count `sig_priority` for specific value?
2. However, when the value does not exist, mysql returns `sig_priority` as `0`?
3. How can I use this code for report a year by the months and report a month per days?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you want to use SUM(sig_priority)?
2. Make default value to 0, then it will return it :)
3. If you want to make a report, than you need a backend language like php. It will be easier with it, and not in sql :)

Comment: Thanks pal . No . I want to Count (sig_priority) but when use " where (timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-10 14:05:00' AND '2018-06-10 15:05:00' ) AND sig_priority=''2 " in mysql and value is not exist no row showed that I want need show row with count 0 value. How I should to do ?